# Android - Control Music Player with Phonegap/SteroidsJS/Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, steroids

I'm currently using Appgyvers SteroidsJS (which is forks of Phonegap and Cordova), and would like to control the default music player from within the app on my Android (5.0.1). Simple things like play, stop, pause, next, and back.

I can't seem to find any direct way to accomplish this, or even a way to pop in to the Android API from Steroids/Phonegap. Does anyone have a solid method to do so or is it not possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing simple existed, so in the end I learnt how to write something myself. :)
https://github.com/dustinblackman/cordova-MusicControl/